# fail2ban error. can´t ban with lighttpd-auth

Tags: lighttpd, iptables, ubuntu-server

today I installed fail2ban in my ubuntu-server.
After this i had to add the following .conf I got at fail2ban on githunb:
/etc/config/filter.d/lighttpd.conf

```
# Fail2Ban filter to match wrong passwords as notified by lighttpd's auth Module
#

[Definition]

failregex = ^: \(http_auth\.c\.\d+\) (password doesn\'t match .* username: .*|digest: auth failed for .*: wrong password|get_password failed), IP: <HOST>\s*$

ignoreregex =

# Author: Francois Boulogne <fboulogne@april.org>
```

After this I added the following lines to my Jail.conf:

```
[lighttpd-auth]

enabled = false
filter  = lighttpd-auth
action  = iptables[name=lighttpd-auth, port="http,https"]
# adapt the following two items as needed
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log
maxretry = 2
```

And now I have the following problem, fail2ban can find the wrong logins, but can´t ban the attacker IP -.-
Here the lines from my file2ban.log

```
2013-11-05 18:23:24,710 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -N fail2ban-lighttpd-auth
iptables -A fail2ban-lighttpd-auth -j RETURN
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport http,https -j fail2ban-lighttpd-auth returned 200
2013-11-05 18:23:59,747 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [lighttpd-auth] Ban 9.999.999.99
2013-11-05 18:23:59,750 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q fail2ban-lighttpd-auth returned 100
2013-11-05 18:23:59,750 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  Invariant check failed. Trying to restore a sane environment
2013-11-05 18:23:59,756 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -N fail2ban-lighttpd-auth
iptables -A fail2ban-lighttpd-auth -j RETURN
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport http,https -j fail2ban-lighttpd-auth returned 200
2013-11-05 18:23:59,758 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -n -L INPUT | grep -q fail2ban-lighttpd-auth returned 100
2013-11-05 18:23:59,758 fail2ban.actions.action: CRITICAL Unable to restore environment
2013-11-05 18:24:01,760 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [lighttpd-auth] 9.999.999.99 already banned
2013-11-05 18:24:02,762 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [lighttpd-auth] 9.999.999.99 already banned
2013-11-05 18:24:04,764 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [lighttpd-auth] 9.999.999.99 already banned
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that fail2ban is calling iptables wrong.

The -dport http,https option does not work with two ports. It gives:

```
iptables v1.4.20: invalid port/service `http,https' specified.
```

The correct call would be

```
iptables [...] -m multiport -dports "http,https" [...]
```

Modify your fail2ban configuration so that it uses the correct call.  Here it works like this:

```
action  = iptables[name=lighttpd-auth, m=multiport ports="http,https"]
```